# Section numbering in Babel

Tags: numbering

For the shown MWE, the main language of the document is Arabic, yet all numbering appear in English (Page numbers, footnotes, section numbers, even alphabetic page numbers) Is there a way to resolve such issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{rm}{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{سسسييسسييس}
\section{ مقدمة}
\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}
\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}
\clearpage
\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}
. حيث حُذِفَت علامة الرفع (وس) وايضاً حُذِفَت الحركة الأولى (أي) والتي ظنها العرب استهلال يتبقى اسم قبط
\index{شبيسبسي}
\index{سيبسيبسي}
وهى مأخوذة من "حام" بن نوح
سيبيسبيسبسيب
سيبيسبيسبسيب
بيلبيلبيلبيلبيلبيل 
\newpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: On my TL 2019 I have correct numbering with your example ١, ٢, ٣, ...... !! what is exactly the problem ?

Comment: CAn it be a windows issue?

Comment: Here is the log file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/jf7en9kcfryqf0q/log.log/file

Comment: I think you need to update your texlive, babel option `mapdigits`  added only with version 3.30 (you have V 3.29)

Comment: Yes, When I updated the packages, the numbers were displayed correctly. THX, issue resolved

Comment: However, the alphabetic numbering is still in English though

Comment: Can you add image showing the issue.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ygs45q0da4mkr74/SA-Solved-no_bib_-_Numbering.pdf/file